# ansible multi dimensional array

Tags: automation, deployment, ansible

i start learning ansible and i try to install PHP and php extensions.
I have a file where i declare my php versions and php extensions and its look like:

```
    php:
  versions:
    - 7.2:
      - cli
      - fpm
      - curl
      - mysql
      - pdo
      - zip
      - xml
      - gd
      - mbstring
      - tokenizer
      - ctype
      - json
    - 7.3:
      - cli
      - fpm
      - curl
      - mysql
      - pdo
      - zip
      - xml
      - gd
      - mbstring
      - tokenizer
      - ctype
      - json
```

I am doing that because i wanna learning ansible, and also for flexibility and to install different extensions for every php versions.

I try to debug my code using this (this is under tasks section in my playbook.yml file)

```
- name: DEBUG ANSIBLE PLAYBOOK
  debug:
    msg: The key is - {{ item.keys() | first }} The item is "{{ item[item.keys() | first] }}"
  loop: "{{ php.versions }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item
```

I get this output:

```
TASK [DEBUG ANSIBLE PLAYBOOK] 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={7.2: [u'cli', u'fpm', u'curl', u'mysql', u'pdo', u'zip', u'xml', u'gd', u'mbstring', u'tokenizer', u'ctype', u'json']}) => {
    "msg": "The key is - 7.2 The item is \"[u'cli', u'fpm', u'curl', u'mysql', u'pdo', u'zip', u'xml', u'gd', u'mbstring', u'tokenizer', u'ctype', u'json']\""
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item={7.3: [u'cli', u'fpm', u'curl', u'mysql', u'pdo', u'zip', u'xml', u'gd', u'mbstring', u'tokenizer', u'ctype', u'json']}) => {
    "msg": "The key is - 7.3 The item is \"[u'cli', u'fpm', u'curl', u'mysql', u'pdo', u'zip', u'xml', u'gd', u'mbstring', u'tokenizer', u'ctype', u'json']\""
}
```

And i try to install PHP using this task:

```
- name: Install PHP
  package:
    pkg: php{{ item.keys() | first }}-{{ item[item.keys() | first] }}
    state: latest
  loop: "{{ php.versions }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: item
  notify: Restart Nginx
```

But is not working because `item[item.keys() | first]` is an array and i don't know how to loop again to receive cli, fpt instead of an array.

I study ansible from 3 days, and i really don't understand how can loop more times. I search on the web, i read documentation, but i don't understand

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html

If someone can explain, i will appreciate very much!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after i research a lot i found a solution

```
- name: Install PHP && Packages
  become: true
  package:
    pkg: php{{ item.0.version }}-{{ item.1 }}
    state: latest
  with_subelements:
    - "{{ php }}"
    - libs
  notify: Restart Nginx
```

This work for me. Also, i change my array:

```
php:
  - version: 7.2
    libs:
      - cli
      - fpm
      - curl
      - mysql
      - pdo
      - zip
      - xml
      - gd
      - mbstring
      - tokenizer
      - ctype
      - json
  - version: 7.3
    libs:
      - cli
      - fpm
      - curl
      - mysql
      - pdo
      - zip
      - xml
      - gd
      - mbstring
      - tokenizer
      - ctype
      - json
```

I let this here, maybe someone will found this helpful.

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to use include_tasks. See the hint below.

```
tasks:
  - include_tasks: test.yml
    loop: "{{ php.versions }}"
    loop_control:
      loop_var: php_ver
```

.

```
> cat test.yml
- debug: msg="{{ lookup('dict', php_ver).key }}"
- debug: msg="{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('dict', php_ver).value }}"
```

Here is the playbook

```
> cat test-31.yml
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
    php:
      versions:
        - 7.2:
            - cli
            - fpm
            - curl
            - mysql
            - pdo
            - zip
            - xml
            - gd
            - mbstring
            - tokenizer
            - ctype
            - json
        - 7.3:
            - cli
            - fpm
            - curl
            - mysql
            - pdo
            - zip
            - xml
            - gd
            - mbstring
            - tokenizer
            - ctype
            - json
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: test.yml
      loop: "{{ php.versions }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: php_ver
```

Here is the output

```
> ansible-playbook test-31.yml | grep msg
    "msg": "7.2"
    "msg": "cli"
    "msg": "fpm"
    "msg": "curl"
    "msg": "mysql"
    "msg": "pdo"
    "msg": "zip"
    "msg": "xml"
    "msg": "gd"
    "msg": "mbstring"
    "msg": "tokenizer"
    "msg": "ctype"
    "msg": "json"
    "msg": "7.3"
    "msg": "cli"
    "msg": "fpm"
    "msg": "curl"
    "msg": "mysql"
    "msg": "pdo"
    "msg": "zip"
    "msg": "xml"
    "msg": "gd"
    "msg": "mbstring"
    "msg": "tokenizer"
    "msg": "ctype"
    "msg": "json"
```

Comment: I get this error: {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while running the lookup plugin 'dict'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: with_dict expects a dict"}.

Comment: I've added the playbook and the output.